# Redirect 301 running domain to another running domain

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, search-results

Let us say I have landing page `a.example` and `b.example` (similar content & brand but different topic), these 2 are running and ranked on SERP, got traffic, but `b.example` is better than `a.example` in SERP with specific competitive keywords (it can be on page 2-3).

The question is, when I do an HTTP 301 redirect from `b.example` to `a.example`, will `a.example` replace the `b.example` in SERP and get better ranking? (maybe jump to page 1), or something else?

Comment: Can you please update your question to provide some additional context? What exactly are you looking to accomplish? Do you own both domains?

Comment: Are you moving the content from `b.example` to `a.example` and setting up a series of redirects, or are you deleting the content? This is important to know to give a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The page you redirect to should eventually replace the redirected site in the search results.

This is not guaranteed, nor are any specific rankings to move higher or lower. But it is the likely outcome.